# sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice adding extra choice field

Tags: forms, symfony1, render

I'm using sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice and I'm reading options from table. Is it easy way to add one option and place as first which is not in this table?

By option I mean html option:

```
<select>
   <option val="new"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always localize the choices, then prepend the resulting array with the value you would like to use:

```
$choice = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'MODEL', 'order_by' => array('name', 'asc')));

$choices = $choice->getChoices();

array_unshift($choices, array('key' => 'My Custom Value'));

$this->widgetSchema['widget_name']      = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $choices));
$this->validatorSchema['widget_name']   = new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys($choices));
```